# sync API calls in Node.JS

Tags: synchronous

Folks
I am not a Node.JS expert and as a product manager of a team that uses Node.JS, I have the following dilemma.

My team uses Node.JS to build a platform of which a business rules engine is a key component. The Rules Engine (RE) has commands to make API calls to various target servers. 
The RE intends to execute its statements in sequential way but my tech team tells me that web API calls are executed in parallel in Node. Hence if have a API call followed by statements which process the data fetched from the API call and then the code passes on the data after some processing to another API call, I am told -- the second API will receive invalid data as it will be executed along with the first API. Is this true?

If so, what are some nice ways to effectively solve without hurting the performance? 
As said earlier, I want statements, irrespective of they being API calls or non-API calls, to be executed in parallel.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's not true. In the callback for the first response, process the data and send off the second response.